# iPhone category for UIImage memory problem

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have a categories class which I put the the image and some color categories that I resuse over the project, I simply use them like:

```
UIImageView *anImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

anImageView.image = [UIImage APP_IMAGE_BCKGROUND];
[window addSubview:anImageView];
[anImageView autorelease];
```

But I have some memory problems, is this way of category usage is a good practise? or how can I define the pictures in a seperate class and memory efficent way?

[image]

Comment: The image you included is really too small to see. Copy the code to your question instead.

Comment: Just wondering -- why autorelease anImageView? Just release it instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the approach you are taking is good practice. The alternative would be to create a `UIImageManager` class which does essentially the same thing. When given these types of alternatives, I typically choose to use categories, unless I find myself adding many new methods to support my requirements. In that case I'll create a separate class. But what you have there looks fine.

There are no leaks in your code. What memory problems are you having?